# How to upgrade postgresql in NixOS?

Tags: postgresql, nixos

I am attempting to update my postgresql server from 9.4 to (at least) 9.6 on my NixOS machine.

I have edited `services.postgres.package` in my `configuration.nix` to reflect this change, changing it from:

```
services.postgresql.package = pkgs.postgresql94
```

to

```
services.postgresql.package = pkgs.postgresql96
```

However, this results in an error upon running `nixos-rebuild switch`, namely:

```
$ sudo nixos-rebuild switch                                                                                                                           
building Nix...
building the system configuration...
stopping the following units: postgresql.service
NOT restarting the following changed units: display-manager.service
activating the configuration...
setting up /etc...
setting up tmpfiles
reloading the following units: dbus.service
restarting the following units: polkit.service
starting the following units: postgresql.service
Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
warning: the following units failed: postgresql.service

● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/nix/store/bh7vzvacc9y56w0kzs1mwgb1jy9bwvf6-unit-postgresql.service/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-08-04 17:39:33 UTC; 26ms ago
  Process: 25399 ExecStartPost=/nix/store/hj8lfb9bbspn76nwm0qmx0xr4466gh0a-unit-script/bin/postgresql-post-start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 25398 ExecStart=/nix/store/qhdnk3qsw00igzadqfxf7kpp3a48z368-unit-script/bin/postgresql-start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 25395 ExecStartPre=/nix/store/qg6s6mph3jmrsgr67vh4bsydxrrbmvrr-unit-script/bin/postgresql-pre-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 25398 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 04 17:39:33 nixos systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Server...
Aug 04 17:39:33 nixos systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 04 17:39:33 nixos systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 04 17:39:33 nixos systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Server.
Aug 04 17:39:33 nixos systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 04 17:39:33 nixos systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
warning: error(s) occurred while switching to the new configuration
```

I notice that the NixOS manual contains a [PostgreSQL section](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#module-postgresql), however the "Upgrading" subsection is not yet filled out. Any ideas on how I might resolve this error and upgrade my PostgreSQL?

Comment: Which NixOS version are you using? What does `journalctl` tell you? NixOS 18.09 will see an [overhauled posgresql](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/38698). Also [this issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/7454) might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a dump of all server databases, whacking the old data_directory and uninstalling the old version, installing the new version, then restoring from the dump.
These steps are described in detail below.

---

Create a dump of all server databases.

```
$ pg_dumpall -U root > sql-dump
```

Identify the location of the current version's `data_directory`.

```
root=# SHOW data_directory;
   data_directory
--------------------
 /var/db/postgresql
(1 row)
```

Change the version of `services.postgresql.package` in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`.

```
services.postgresql.package = pkgs.postgresql100
```

This is apparently the expression for version 10.4, according to `$ nix-env -qaP '*' --description`.

Next whack the `data_directory` for the current version.

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/db/postgresql/
```

And switch to the new version marked in `configuration.nix`

```
$ sudo nixos-rebuild switch
```

I had to create a `root` db.

```
$ sudo createdb root
```

(I also had to change some instances of `postgres` to `root` in my `sql-dump` file.)

Restore the data into the new version.

```
$ psql -U root -f sql-dump
```

---

Anyone know how one can contribute to the [nixos manual](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/)?
I am happy to use what I've learned here to write up the [updating postgres section](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#idm140737315956256).

Comment: you could also use `pg_upgrade` tool https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html instead of dump (but generally procedure seems fine)

Comment: the [nixos manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/#module-services-postgres-upgrading) has an example with `pg_upgrade`